# (Ionic) Write on NFC tag protected by a password using Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, passwords, nfc, phonegap

I'd like to know if it's possible to write on NFC tag protected by a password using Cordova/Phonegap ?
I can read any tag and it doesn't matter if it is protected or not !
But my main problem is in the question above, because I searched on Internet and there's no place where I can find a solution to this problem...
I use Ionic 3.2.0 and Cordova for NFC

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge there is no password protection available for the NDEF format, which is the most used NFC-tag technology (see e.g., https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/beginning-nfc/9781449324094/ch04.html). From a technical point of view it is hard to imagine how this might be even realised.

To my best knowledge iOS only supports NDEF. Android can be used with other formats, more information on that can be found in the NFC advanced section (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc)

I would recommend to store the payload encrypted with a password and decrypt it after reading. Encrypting/descrypting of a string can be done with a javavscript library (depending on the algorithm). Reading/Writing of NFC tags can be done with a cordova plugin: https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc

Comment: You can passwort-protect WRITING an NDEF message (i.e. replacing an NDEF message). As the phonegap-nfc plugin supports a transparent exchange command, you can do it, but would need to make sure you have the right NFC tag/card in front of your phone (in other words - you would need to code that for all different card types, there is no abstractt function like NDEF-WRITE.)